# todonotes alternative

Tags: overleaf, forward-inverse-search, todonotes

I'm using Overleaf, and because of `todonotes` package the inverse search doesn't work:

> Couldn't find the corresponding source file.

It's a known error: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/SyncTeX_Errors:

> The todonotes package also loads the fadings library, so may also cause SyncTeX to fail.

Are there `todonotes` alternatives without this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. See https://www.ctan.org/topic/notes for some possible alternatives. Currently your question is a bit broad - maybe you can specify what you would consider a valid alternative, i.e., which conditions or features should such a package satisfy?

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. The conditions are: it works with LaTeX, SyncTex works, it shows visually-distinguishable notes, it doesn't mess up commonly-used packages, it can be disabled with a single option/command.